# Wifi not working in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-device-driver

I m trying to work wifi in ubuntu 10.04 lts on HP pavilion dv6 laptop. I m new to Ubuntu

I tried many thing , that were present online with Broadcom. I feel Broadmcom is not present.

Please find the output of lspci command below.

```
zxc@zxc-laptop:~$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1e16] (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1e1a] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1e57] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation Mobile 82801 SATA RAID Controller [8086:282a] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation Device [10de:0de9] (rev a1)
08:00.0 Class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: RaLink Device [1814:539a]
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI     Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
```

Comment: I would say you better switch to windows :D

Comment: I cannot see a wireless device listed there in lspci output. Do you have a windows install in the same machine and is it showing your wireless card in device manager?

Comment: Yes , I have Windows 7, it is Ralink RT5390R 802.11b/g/n 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter

Comment: try linux Mint it comes with wireless drivers pre-installed.

Comment: Hi @user1141584, 

May you please try this post, it seems that it can work with Ralink wireless cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous, significant networking bugs in older Ubuntu versions; the networking utilities have been substantially reworked in recent versions. Before doing anything else rather than chasing possibly already fixed bugs I'd suggest seeing if you can boot a recent ubuntu (12.04) desktop CD. That runs off the CD and doesn't require modifying your install.

Comment: Thanks , I would try with Ubuntu 12.04 lts and check that...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact laptop.  The vanilla kernel from version 3.8 up to 3.9.4 is broken for this wifi adaptor.  The patch found on this link will revert changes to the driver to make it work like it did in 3.7.10 (no stability or performance problems).

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=950735